# How to call a UIView from a UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I need to create a transparent `UIView` with an `UIActivityIndicator` and an `UIImage` on it.
I found a code [from a tutorial](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/11/creating-transparent-uiviews-rounded.html) as in how to create the Round edge `UIView`.

1. Can someone help me call this `UIView` from my `UIViewController` class. (To call a `UIViewConroller` from another  `UIViewController` we use the following code;)

   ViewOne *v1 = [ViewOne alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
     [self.navigationController v1 animated:YES];

but this doesn't work when calling UIView's. So how can i call it ?

1. To add an UIImage and a UIActivity indicator programatically to the UIView ?

Comment: The code is in the Link that i have posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every view controller has a view property. Just use `UIView *yourView = yourViewController.view` to get it. From there you can use `[yourView addSubView:someOtherView]` to add the activity indicator and the image, as well as setting the transparency.

Comment: So will `UIView *yourView = yourViewController.view` call my UIView ?

Comment: Yes, `yourViewController.view` is the call to get the view controller's view.

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't you just wire up the UIView to an IBOutlet, and then just add your programmatically created view to the outlet

Comment: Can you post me a link to a tutorial that explains how to do this ?